# What is the lowest number/percentage of votes technically required to form a government in a list PR system?

Tags: voting, proportional-representation

In a totally hypothetical scenario, what is the lowest number/percentage of votes required to form a government in a democratic list Proportional representation system?

Assume there are no artificial thresholds or other complicating factors. I would then suppose it's whatever is required to have at least one seat in parliament. Then a (minority) government could be formed with just one MP vote.

Am I correct, or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2):

If the constitution requires that the person who forms the government is an MP, then the number of votes needed is the minimum required to win one seat. This is also true in first-past-the-post and STV systems.

In principle, any MP can build a coalition and then form a government. In practice it might (rarely) happen that an independent MP will be asked to form a government (perhaps a "government of national unity") when the major parties are seen to have failed. (I can't think of an actual time when this occurred).

Of course to build a coalition, you need to gain the support of MPs who (in proportional systems) represent more than 50% of the voters.

<sub>In systems in which the person forming the government does not need to be an MP, then no votes are required: most well known is the US system. There, 270 votes are all that are required to become president, and your party does not need to have won a single seat in Parliament (=Congress)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

> Assume there are no artificial thresholds or other complicating
> factors. I would then suppose it's whatever is required to have at
> least one seat in parliament. Then a (minority) government could be
> formed with just one MP vote.
>
> Correct?

In most parliamentary systems, you can only form a government, at least as a first shot effort before anyone else has tried and failed, with the invitation of the monarch (or a Governor-General representing a monarch), in a constitutional monarchy, or the President, in a republic which has no monarchy.

So, to form a minority government, you need to be asked to form one. There are good reasons in parliamentary procedure why even a minority government needs at least two MPs (one to move that the minority government be formed and one to second the motion), but you only get to make the motion if you are given leave to do so.

In practice, the monarch or President, by long tradition, will almost always ask the leader of the party with the largest representation in parliament to form a government first (although this issue is not justiciable), unless another party can credibly demonstrate that it would be futile for that party to attempt to do so because another coalition with a majority of MPs has already announced that it will form a majority government.

Comment: There are two systems of government formation in parliamentary states: the one described in this answer, where the head of state invites someone to try and form one, which must then be confirmed by parliament; and the other, where - once parties have negotiated amongst themselves - MPs nominate candidates, and parliament itself chooses who will be PM (which may then be followed by a formal appointment by the head of state). The end result may well be the same, but I thought it might be worth including in the answer.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff Fair enough. I'm not familiar with the later examples so I can't speak to them. This would still be a minimum of two MPs. Also, when you get majority support on the PM vote how do you distinguish a coalition government from a minority government?